# JSON Web Services Liferay

Tags: json, liferay

I'm following this tutorial to create liferay json services (http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/JSON+Web+Services) , but i'm getting the following error :

```
14:03:29,294 ERROR [pool-2-thread-5][JSONWebServiceServiceAction:54] java.lang.NullPointerException
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.liferay.portal.jsonwebservice.JSONWebServiceConfigurator.configure(JSONWebServiceConfigurator.java:101)
        at com.liferay.portal.jsonwebservice.JSONWebServiceServiceAction.<init>(JSONWebServiceServiceAction.java:51)
        at com.liferay.portal.jsonwebservice.JSONWebServiceServlet.getJSONAction(JSONWebServiceServlet.java:169)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.JSONServlet.init(JSONServlet.java:52)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortalClassLoaderServlet.portalInit(PortalClassLoaderServlet.java:76)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.PortalLifecycleUtil.register(PortalLifecycleUtil.java:64)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.PortalLifecycleUtil.register(PortalLifecycleUtil.java:56)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortalClassLoaderServlet.init(PortalClassLoaderServlet.java:47)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1266)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1185)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1080)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5015)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5302)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:895)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:871)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1099)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1621)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Have I missed a setting? Is there some additional configuration needed?

Thanks.

Comment: What Liferay version do you use and when this exception is thrown?

Comment: Liferay 6.1.1-ce-ga2, and the exception is thrown after Spring root WebApplicationContext is initialized when i'm starting Tomcat Server. I have some services anotated @JSONWebService and web.xml configured as in tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have services.properties in your src. Service Builder is mandatory to be used for json webservices in liferay.